# How do I set up virtual IPs on a private LAN?

Tags: networking, ip, virtualization, heartbeat

I am setting up heartbeat on a few servers that will only be responding on the private lan (192.168.1.x). We are using a sonicwall 2400 router. How do I go about setting up some of those IPs to be virtual, so that heartbeat will listen to them and I don't have to bind them to each server?

Comment: This is entirely dependent on the high availability technology you will be using. We need more information.

Answer (score 0):

You don't "setup" IP addresses to be "virtual", inasmuch as nothing external to the cluster needs to know that the IP addresses are "virtual".  You just tell heartbeat to manage the IP address across the cluster, and it takes care of the rest.